# Shift all zeros in 2d matrix

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a 2d array like this:

```
2 0 0 2 0 4
2 0 0 2 0 4
2 0 0 2 0 4
```

And I want to shift all the zeros to the left, so for that I made this method:

```
public static void shiftLeft(int [][] array){

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

            if ((array[j][i] != 0) && (array[j][i + 1] == 0)) {
                array[j][i + 1] = array[j][i];
                array[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the output I get is this:

```
0 0 2 0 2 4
0 0 2 0 2 4
0 0 2 0 2 4
```

How can I make all zeros to go to the left?

Comment: You need `for (int i = 0; i < array[j].length - 1; i++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way to do this is using 3 nested loops.

Variable **i** iterates over the rows.

Variable **j1** finds the first nonzero element starting from the left of each row.

Variable **j2** finds the first zero element after **j1** and swaps them.
The code below assumes that the bidimensional matrix A was declared as **A[N][M]**, where N and M are respectively the number of rows and number of columns.

```
for(int i =0;i<N;i++){
  for(int j1=0;j1<M;j1++){
    if (A[i][j1]==0)
      continue;
    for(int j2=j1;j2<M;j2++){
      if( A[i][j2]==0){
         //swap
         int tmp=A[i][j1];
         A[i][j1]=A[i][j2];
         A[i][j2]=tmp;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm worked me but sometimes, when the initial matrix has several non-zero values together without a space (0) in between, the final result after calling the method results in some of those values swaping themselves.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159755/array-shifter-method-not-fully-working#47159755

code is not working @Trugis. Can you please check your code and explain here.

Comment: @FacundoSchiavoni Could you please give me the input you are using that is causing the algorithm not to behave correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In fact Trugis's answer is also correct but it will just swap the zero with the first non zero. So the order of the numbers will change.

This answer will not change the order of the numbers :

```
    int[][] A = {   { 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0 },
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    { 2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 }};

    int N = A.length;
    int M = A[0].length;
    int firstZeros = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { // Loop over the rows 
        for(int j1 = 0; j1 < M; j1++) {
            // If there is a zero we pass by
            if (A[i][j1] == 0 && firstZeros == j1) {
                firstZeros++;
                continue;
            }
            // Otherwise, we have a value so we want to check if there is a zero afterwards
            for(int j2 = j1+1; j2 < M; j2++) {
                // If we find a zero we move it to the left
                if(A[i][j2] == 0) {
                    for (int j3 = j2; j3 > firstZeros; j3--) {
                        // Change zero with previous value
                        A[i][j3] = A[i][j3-1];
                        A[i][j3-1] = 0;
                    }
                    firstZeros++;
                }
            }
        }
        firstZeros = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I tested your algorithm and compared it with mine, you can see my test code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zA2HcR9n).
Your output ( the output is written as a comment at the bottom of the code ) seems wrong.

Comment: Wow my solution is so wrong :-p
You should correct yours to avoid swapping and changing the order of the numbers, that's what I tried to do without success I suppose ^^

Comment: So I updated my answer to something that actually works, this time I tested it but you can take a look by yourself.